# Struts form empty

Tags: java, forms, jsp, struts

Good morning,
I am trying to pass a form from a JSP to a Action.
The form compiles correctly if I pass the parameters in the URL (?par=value ...) but it does not if I use submit and form value.

I think everything is set up correctly, but I must be missing something.

I've already searched other similar posts, but I couldn't find a solution.

**The problem is that the form that arrives in the Action "new" method is empty.**

struts.config.xml:

```
<form-bean name="EsempioForm" type="com.forms.EsempioForm"/>
<action name="EsempioForm" parameter="method" input="/pages/esempio.jsp" path="/esempio" scope="request" type="com.EsempioAction">
<forward ... />
</action>
```

esempio.jsp:

```
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-html.tld" prefix="html" %>
...
<html:form action="/esempio">
<input type="hidden" id="method" name="method" value="new"/>
<html:text property="desc" disabled="true" />
<html:submit styleClass="button">record</html:submit>
</html:form>
```

EsempioAction.java

```
public ActionForward new(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    ...
    EsempioForm esempioForm = (esempioForm) form;
    ...
    return mapping.findForward(...);
}
```

Can anyone please help me?
Thank you very much for any advice.

Comment: Share compilation error as well.

Comment: There is no compilation error. Simply the form is empty while it should be valued.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `<html:hidden property="method" value="new" />` instead.

EDIT:

`disabled="true"` disabled fields are not posted on form submit. Make it readonly if you want to submit.

Comment: thank you for your ansewr. But the hidden paramether passes correctly, in fact tne "new" method is executed. The problem is about the other patamethers, in the example the property "desc" that passes empty, while in the jsp page it has a correct value.

Comment: Thank you, it's correct. The disabled propery caused the problem, and I could not find it because of another error in a javascript of mine. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Change `<html:form action="/esempio">` to `<html:form action="/esempio" method="POST">` and try again.

Edit 1: the property desc is not being passed?

> Does it anything to do with  disabled="true" (just suspecting) property?

Comment: How GET or POST make a difference?

Comment: GET takes data from the URl, while POST take data from the body post. It makes difference in the way data is sent to the server in HTTP request. Read more http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp

Comment: Yes but what makes the hidden parameter not being passed for GET and will be passed for POST. I mean does you answer solve the problem ? If so how?

Comment: I don't think that the hidden variable would ever passed by URL parameter? But it would be definitely passed in a post parameter.

Comment: the hidden variable is correctly passed, the problem is about the other variables, all the variables in the forms in the action page are in facts empty.

Comment: I don't think the problem is about the disabled property. I tried by removing the attribute but it still doesn't work.

Comment: I was wrong. The disabled propery caused the problem, and I could not find it because of another error in a javascript of mine. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The properties you are trying to pass through your html form should be present in your form bean class. There should always be a mapping for any property to a variable in your form except when you pass any hidden values using `<input type="hidden" id="method" name="method" value="new"/>`. In this case, you don't need a corresponding mapping in your form!

Comment: the property I am trying to pass is present in the form bean class